# Why are you deleting some posts?

Tags: discussion

Why was you delete Valorant shirk posts?

Answer (score 3):

From a cursory site search, the only deleted "Valorant shirk post" I found was https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/69063/22.

This post was deleted by automatic system processes, which automatically deletes old, unanswered questions that have a negative score after a month. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/132874 for more details.

If this is not the deleted question you are referring to, please update your meta question here with more details.